# TanStack Table (React-Table) | How to convert the column filter state into the format that the backend is excepting?

Tags: reactjs, nestjs, react-table, react-table-v7, react-table-v8

I'm trying to implement server-side column filtering for a table in my React app, but I'm having trouble converting the "ColumnFiltersState" object that I'm using on the frontend into the format that the backend (which uses the "nestjs-paginate" library) is expecting. The "ColumnFiltersState" object contains a "value" field that can be of type "unknown" and I'm not sure how to handle it. I have a couple of possible solutions in mind:

One solution could be to use the "filterFn" property for each column, and pass in the filter operator that the backend is expecting (e.g. '$eq', '$gt', etc.) along with the value.
Another approach would be to define a separate mapping function that maps the "ColumnFiltersState" object into the format that the backend is expecting, using the appropriate filter operator and value for each column, but then how we would know witch operator to use, maybe add custom meta prop to the coulmnDef.
Can anyone provide some guidance on how to correctly map the column filters for the backend, and which solution would be the best approach? I would really appreciate any feedback or advice on the best approach, and even better if there is an example code to help me understand the solution better.